# Laravel : Search Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

This is my query for getting data within multiple tables.

Query Look :

```
$userPostDetails = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
                    ->orderBy('id','desc')
                    ->get();
```

It is return all data according to my query.

Now what I want I have search within all tables in query which is

`[Post,Products,post_attributes,attrbute,category,users,userdetails]`

so if in my search parameter if I have a search parameter for

`categroyTitle`

it will return with search details.If it is `NULL` return all.

Same for all tables I want to search :

If In I want to search within `posts` table for `Active` post what I tried

```
if(isset($any_or_active)) {
   $is_any_active = $any_or_active;
 }
```

and add this in Above query 
`->whereIn('demand_or_supply', $is_demand_supply)`

but what if

`$is_demand_supply` is `NULL` ?

How can I do this ?

Comment: your question its so messy ask more clearly

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi can you please tell me that what you do not understand ?

Answer (score 1):

I think using Laravel Searchable (sofa eloquence) will help.

run 
composer require sofa/eloquence

in each model 
for example

```
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence;
protected $searchableColumns = [
   'country.name'(relation) => 20 (weight),
   'user.email' => 10,
   'user.name' => 25,
   'user.type' => 5,
   'gender' (attribute) => 10 (weight),
   'nationality' => 2,
];
```

this is link for this package on github
https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence

and from its site, this is a detailed explanation 
https://softonsofa.com/laravel-searchable-the-best-package-for-eloquent/

hope it helps.